# Creating button dynamically doesn't have the onclick parameter

Tags: javascript, html, button, dynamic

I have this method for creating new buttons:

```
function createButton(buttonId, buttonClass, clickEvent) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = buttonId;
    button.className = buttonClass;
    button.onclick = function(){
        clickEvent;
    };

    return button;
 }
```

That I call in this way:

```
var editButton = createButton(
      "edit-" + string + "-allow",
      "btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-edit-lg",
      allowEdit("edit-" + string + "-allow")
);
```

But checking on the element inspector the onclick property is not added
[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: would be better to use addEventListener ion the new created button

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function name and the parameter. Otherwise it will execute when assigned

Also I suggest to use eventListener instead of onclick

```js
const allowEdit = str => console.log(str)

const createButton = (buttonId, buttonClass, clickEvent, parameter) =>{
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = buttonId
  button.id = buttonId;
  button.className = buttonClass;
  button.addEventListener("click", () => clickEvent(parameter))
  return button;
};

let string = 'temp';
let editButton = createButton(
  `edit-${string}-allow`,
  "btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-edit-lg",
  allowEdit, `edit-${string}-allow`
);

document.body.appendChild(editButton);
```

If the button click is the same and only the parameter changes; I suggest delegation:

```js
const allowEdit = str => console.log(str)

const createButton = (buttonId) => {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = buttonId;
  button.id = buttonId;
  return button;
};

const container = document.getElementById("buttonContainer");
let strings = ['temp1','temp2','temp3'].forEach(str => container.appendChild(createButton(`edit-${str}-allow`)));

container.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
  if (!tgt) return; // not a button
  allowEdit(tgt.textContent.trim());
})
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer"></div>
```